# Image Stack Color Analysis

Tags: imagej

I have a few images of the same rock with each of them revealing the presence of a certain element in a different color. So one of them will show bright green when Silicon is present, another may show dark red where Calcium is present, etc.

Is there any way to overlay these and be able to tell what is the concentration of all the minerals at a given point on the rock?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to overlay these

If you have seven or fewer images, you can open the images and make them into a single image stack using Image > Stacks > Images to Stack. Or open them using File > Import > Image Sequence if they are numbered. Or if they are all RGB, you can blend them using the Image Calculator (Process > Image Calculator). If you do end up with a single stack, you can use ImageJ's Composite image feature (Image > Color > Make Composite) to overlay the colors.

> and be able to tell what is the concentration of all the minerals at a given point on the rock?

That part is harder. You may face some of the same challenges of colocalization analysis. Qualitative analysis is too subjective, and human eyes are too easily fooled. See [Why scatter plots instead of colour merge images](http://fiji.sc/Colocalization_Analysis#Why_scatter_plots_instead_of_colour_merge_images.3F) on the Fiji wiki for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [RGB composer plugin](http://www.astro.physik.uni-goettingen.de/~hessman/ImageJ/RGB_Composer/).  It will take grayscale images and turn them into the R, G, and B channels of a color image.  (Note you must downconvert to 8 bit.)  It has great settings for adjusting the color intensities to make features pop.

If you want to do quantitative ratios, you have to make sure that your element maps are quantitative atomic weight rather than simple count or intensity maps.  If you have made sure that your maps are quantitative, then it becomes a powerful way to rapidly find the phases you are interested in.  For example when looking for olivine, I will often produce an Mg, Fe, and Si map.  Then I use the Image Expression Parser command to make an image from (Mg+Fe)/Si.  Pixels which have olivine will be pretty close to 2.